# Handling selection change in view-model for DataGrid.ScrollIntoView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have the following view-model class:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected {
        get => _isSelected;
        set {
            if (value == _isSelected) { return; }
            _isSelected = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsSelected)));
        }
    }

    public int Data { get; }
    public ViewModel(int data) => Data = data;
}
```

and the following view:

```
<Window x:Class="MVVMScrollIntoView.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <DataGrid Name="dg">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
      <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
      </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
  </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

I set the `ItemsSource` of the DataGrid in the code-behind as follows:

```
var data = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(x => new ViewModel(x)).ToList();
dg.ItemsSource = data;
```

Selecting/deselecting rows in the data grid is propogated to the view-model instances, and changes from code to the view-model's `IsSelected` property are propogated back to the data grid.

But I want that when the `IsSelected` property is set via code within the view model:

```
data[79].IsSelected = true;
```

the selected data grid row should also scroll into view, presumably using the data grid's `ScrollIntoView` method.

---

My original thought was to listen in the view code-behind for the `SelectionChanged` event:

```
dg.SelectionChanged += (s, e) => dg.ScrollIntoView(dg.SelectedItem);
```

But this doesn't work, as `SelectionChanged` is only triggered on visible items when virtualization is on.

Turning virtualization off is a successful workaround:

```
<DataGrid Name="dg" EnableRowVirtualization="False">
   ...
```

but I'm worried about the performance implications for large lists (20K+ items), so I would prefer not to do this.

---

What's the MVVM way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not like referencing View controls in your ViewModels, but this will work.

Create a reference to the `DataGrid` in your `ViewModel` and invoke the `ScrollIntoView` command in the `Data` setter.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get => _isSelected;
        set
        {
            if (value == _isSelected) { return; }
            _isSelected = value;
             PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsSelected)));

             //Invoke Scroll
             DataGrid.ScrollIntoView(this);
        }
    }

    public int Data { get; }
    public ViewModel(int data) => Data = data;

    //DataGrid Reference
    public DataGrid DataGrid { get; set; }
}
```

Then just add the reference when you construct the ViewModels

```
var data = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(x => new ViewModel(x) { DataGrid = dg }).ToList();
```

It seems like the best way to avoid virtualization and having to call from the View in this case.

Comment: The referenced post brings up some great points, but whew, staying strict MVVM just isn't worth the headache sometimes.

Comment: @Tronald Disagree with you. All things can be solved without breaking a MVVM pattern and wey should be done such a way.

Comment: @Rekshino In a perfect MVVM world with a magnitude of time and resources you are correct. Not every scenario fits that case though. Staying MVVM doesn’t always give you an advantage. Even John Gossman (it’s creator) states this.

Comment: @Rekshino You're invited to post your own answer if you have a better way to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Since I'm invited to post an answer, here it is.
There is several ways to do it with MVVM depending on requirements (single/extended selection only selection or also deselection etc.).
Since you want to use a virtualization, then

- you have to notify the `DataGrid`, that selection is changed
- you have to react on the selection change with `ScrollIntoView`

To implement **first point** you have to

- paste to the "parent"-ViewModel a `CurrentlySelected` property
- bind it with `DataGrid.SelectedItem`
- set `CurrentlySelected` if `IsSelected` being changed, there are also several ways, but e.g. you can pass a reference of the parent-ViewModel to the child.

To implement **second point** you can e.g. use an event handler for `DataGrid.SelectionChanged`, but I would prefer to put this functionality into behavior for it's not in code behind and you can reuse it.

Parent ViewModel:

```
ViewModel _currentlySelected;
public ViewModel CurrentlySelected
{
    get
    {
        return _currentlySelected;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_currentlySelected != value)
        {
            _currentlySelected = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentlySelected));
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool _isSelected;

    public ParentVM ParentRef { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get => _isSelected;
        set
        {
            if (value == _isSelected) { return; }
            _isSelected = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsSelected)));
            if (ParentRef != null && _isSelected)
            {
                ParentRef.CurrentlySelected = this;
            }
        }
    }

    public int Data { get; }
    public ViewModel(int data) => Data = data;
}
```

Initialization:

```
 var data = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(x => new ViewModel(x){ParentRef=(this.DataContext as ParentVM)}).ToList();

dg.ItemsSource = data;
```

Behavior:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

public class ScrollSelectedIntoView : Behavior<DataGrid>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        AssociatedObject?.ScrollIntoView(AssociatedObject?.SelectedItem);
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged;

        base.OnDetaching();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" EnableRowVirtualization="True"
            SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentlySelected}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:ScrollSelectedIntoView/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Solid MVVM answer! If you have the time and resources to strict MVVM, this is certainly the way to go so thanks for this. If the advantages of strict MVVM aren't applicable (which I find is often the case in smaller applications) it's ok to break from MVVM, but if they are applicable, your answer is what should be used.

Comment: Thanks for this; just some random thoughts: 1) In my case, I need extended selection, and both selection and deselection. 2) It makes more sense to me that only the parent should know about the child, but the child should not know about the parent. I would think the parent should listen to the child's `PropertyChanged`. 3) Once I'm adding an event handler to the child view-model, I don't think there's any need for a parent view-model; I can add handlers directly to the child's `PropertyChanged` when I create them.

Comment: @ZevSpitz I understand. As I wrote there are several ways and it depends on requirements and to elaborate all this ways is out of scope of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a ParentViewModel and hydrate a List, with another property that holds a reference to the SelectedViewModel, then subscribe to each of the ViewModel's PropertyChanged events. When the ParentViewModel receives a notification that a ViewModel's IsSelected property has been changed, it sets its SelectedViewModel to that sender. Then in the View, you subscribe to the ParentViewModel's PropertyChanged and check when SelectedViewModel is updated, and then zoom the datagrid to that item.

**Code Behind**

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{
  public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    private bool _isSelected;

    public ViewModel(int data)
    {
      Data = data;
    }

    public int Data { get; }
    public bool IsSelected
    {
      get { return _isSelected; }
      set
      {
        if (value == _isSelected) return;
        _isSelected = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsSelected)));
      }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  }

  public class ParentViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    private ViewModel _selectedViewModel;

    public ParentViewModel(List<ViewModel> viewModels)
    {
      ViewModels = viewModels;
      foreach (var vm in viewModels)
      {
        vm.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
          if (args.PropertyName != nameof(ViewModel.IsSelected)) return;
          SelectedViewModel = vm;
        };
      }
    }

    public ViewModel SelectedViewModel
    {
      get { return _selectedViewModel; }
      set
      {
        if (value == _selectedViewModel) return;
        _selectedViewModel = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedViewModel)));
      }
    }

    public List<ViewModel> ViewModels { get; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    private ParentViewModel _parentViewModel;
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      var parentViewModel = new ParentViewModel(Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(x => new ViewModel(x)).ToList());
      _parentViewModel = parentViewModel;

      _parentViewModel.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) =>
      {
        if (args.PropertyName != nameof(ParentViewModel.SelectedViewModel)) return;

        var selectedViewModel = _parentViewModel.SelectedViewModel;
        if (selectedViewModel != null && selectedViewModel.IsSelected)
        {
          this.dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(selectedViewModel);
        }
      };

      dataGrid.ItemsSource = _parentViewModel.ViewModels;
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      _parentViewModel.ViewModels[66].IsSelected = true;
    }
  }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <DataGrid Name="dataGrid"
              EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
              EnableRowVirtualization="True">
      <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
          <Setter Property="IsSelected"
                  Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </Style>
      </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"
            Content="Click" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: In principle this would also work (I actually have a parent VM). But I don't really like this because if I have to swap out the old parent view model, I also have to remove the handler from the old parent VM and apply it to the new parent VM.

Comment: Right. You would want to unsubscribe if you ever swap at the destructor of the ParentViewModel and do a check on DataContextChanged in the View. In my view, I would rather this extra work than to have a reference to a UI namespace in my ViewModels, since I then tie it to WPF. But it all just depends

Comment: I [made the property type `dynamic`](https://github.com/zspitz/ANTLR4ParseTreeVisualizer/blob/master/Shared/ViewModels/VisualizerDataViewModel.cs#L132), so no UI namespace needed.

Comment: You could probably simply it even further and just require an Action<object> callback when constructing your parent vm to eliminate duck typing and allow for easier testing down the line. That would also allow you to remove the reference to the dynamic object.

Comment: There is one slight disadvantage to using a callback -- the callback inevitably holds a reference to the entire containing class. For example, if the callback is passed in the code-behind of a window, the callback also includes an implicit reference to the window instance. It might be a problem if a single view-model is shared between views. A reference to the control is probably going to be smaller.